# Azure AD Authentication & HTML pages

Tags: html, azure, authentication

We have developed interactive website PoC using HTML5 and Javascript. I have deployed it on Azure WebApp and it is working fine there.

Now as we want to limit the access using Azure Active Directory.

How to implement this?

I saw many links (including Microsoft) talks about tenant, client id and App ID but i am still confused on how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this link (Microsoft).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/

I have personally achieved this following this link. So, if you get stuck anywhere feel free to comment. I'll help you out.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Flemin,

Thanks for quick reply

I have done the same with "Configure Azure Active Directory using express settings" but still anybody can open website and i want only with given users within Azure AD should be allowed

So i am not sure, what i am missing here

Comment: Please follow the Manual Approach. Its a bit long but effective. :D

Comment: So i executed manual approach, but i do not understood
" Action to take when request is not authenticated to Log in with Azure Active Directory "
What exactly i need to do here ?

Comment: In the AppService section in new portal, go to your application. In the settings section, select "Authentication / Authorization". There you'll find this section with a drop down. Select "Log in with Active Directory" from the drop down.

Comment: ah, my bad, that i have selected in the beginning itself
Yes, it is working now, thanks for your quick help

Just want to know few things
* Want to know how it works, any link ?
* Similar way i can implement it for Asp.Net / MVC / WebApi ?

Comment: It should work for any application that has a valid URL. I don't have any links to how it works, but my best guess is Azure tries to authenticate any URL that is appended to the URL which is configured in the Active Directory Applications. If I get any link, I'll surely let you know.

Comment: Thanks Flemin for your quick and extended help